# How can I create an efficient hash function for a a list of numbers with a range of over a billion?

Tags: python, hash, range

I am writing a script in python and I am attempting to create a hash table for `647050` values (most values occur twice, but no more than 3-4 times) taken from a column of a csv file. They have an incredible range with the minimum value being `651` and the maximum being `2147477024`.

**How can I create an efficient hash function which can place `647050` values with a range of `2147476373` into a hash table in a sensible amount of time?**

**And how might I structure the code?**

For example I have tried a simple (but also messy) hash function below which eventually slows to such a crawl that I haven't allowed it to complete. I timed it by different intervals of values successfully added to the hash table so I could see this exponential slow down (it doesn't slow down to an absolute crawl until over `640000` keys have been processed).

The values were all initialized to `0`:

```
def hash_function(value):
    hash_key = value % 647050
    return hash_key

def is_inserted(hash_table, hash_key, num):
    if hash_table[hash_key] == 0:
        hash_table[hash_key] = num
        return True
    return False

def insert(hash_table, hash_key, num):
    current_hash = hash_key
    inserted = False
    while not inserted:
        if current_hash == 647049: #prevent array out of bounds
            current_hash = 0: 
        inserted = is_inserted(hash_table, current_hash, num)
        current_hash += 1

def main():
    #some code
    hash_table = [0] * 647050
    for num in nums
        hash_key = hash_function(num)
        insert(hash_table, hash_key, num)
    #some code
```

**EDIT/CLARIFICATION :** I'm sure if I asked the question correctly. But basically I need to later search the list of all values for matching entries (for about `300` values), and I want to of course avoid nested for each loops which do `647050` checks for each of the `300` values. I then thought of placing the values into a list based on a hash function so that I could then search for them quickly. But I am not sure how to implement this. My current simple implementation creates far too many collisions and takes forever.

Comment: Why not use the python dictionary?  I seriously doubt you could implement a better hash table than the python dictionary implements.

Comment: Profile your code.  I believe you'll find that your it's not `hash_function` taking up  so much time.  When your table is nearly full, each insertion is likely to collide.  Then you search slot-by-slot to find an empty slot.  As empty slots become rare this becomes common and the searches take longer and longer.  What are you trying to accomplish here.  What are you using `hash_table` for?

Comment: If you have the nums loaded already, its a simple matter. See here https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Yea, that's where I'm held up. How can I avoid the amount of collisions that occur? Maybe I'm not sure exactly what I want, but I want to search these values afterwards for matching entries and using nested for each loops would take forever.

Comment: @CBrown77  You're trying to solve a problem that python has already solved for you.  Stop thinking about how to make your own hash table because the python `dict` IS A HASH table.  Use the python `dict` or rephrase your question because currently what you're asking for is not a smart thing to do.

Comment: "I want to search these values afterwards for matching entries."  What's wrong with throwing all these values into a `set`?  It has fast membership testing.  If you need to preserve duplicates use a `collections.counter` (which has the same fast membership testing).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski a `set` has a better best case search than a dictionary, but for average/worst case search performance `dict.has_key(value)` is probably better.  It doesn't seem necessary to use both a `set` and a `Counter` considering the `Counter` is from a `dict` and has all of the features of a `set` except faster.

Comment: @Matt:  "a `set` has a better best case search than a dictionary."  Can you back that up?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski  Yes I tested this using profiling tools built into the `ipython` interpreter.  You can use the `%timeit` command.  I can post a picture if interested.  Intuitively, to search a hash table you need to call a hashing function, check if the hash table has a valid value in the position pointed to by the hash value, and then perform a comparison.  To search a `set` in best case fashion you simply compare against the first element in the sequence.  There are more levels of indirection in the `dict` in other words.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski This is basic algorithms.  Sequences versus hash tables.  All of that assumed that no hashing collisions occurred as well which would restart the process all over which is determined by the probing algorithm

Comment: @Matt:  A python `set` is a hash table.  The initial pure-Python implementation of `set` (introduced in Python 2.3) used a Python dictionary to store its values as keys mapped to `None`.  It wasn't until Python 2.5 that `set` was implemented in C, but it maintained the same algorithmic characteristics.  TLDR: A python `set` is a valueless dictionary.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I have to retract my "intuitive" analysis then haha.  I wasn't actually aware of the internal implementation of `set`.  It does have a better best case performance still though, but I retract the "average" case analysis and the "worst" case performance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, this should do all the job:

```
hash_table = {i:nums[i] for i in range(647050)}
```

I am using Python's builtin dictionary, it seems to be more efficient than using lists.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you didn't understand the question correctly.  He is not storing counts of numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Do this instead.  I don't think you should re-invent the wheel here.

```
def is_inserted(hash_table, num):
    return hash_table.has_key(num)

def insert(hash_table, num):
    if not hash_table.has_key(num):
        hash_table[num] = 1
    else:
        hash_table[num] += 1

def main():
    #some code
    h_table = {}
    for num in nums
        insert(h_table, num)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this would help. I can't create an array of the size of the maximum value in my list. I also think you mean `hash_table[num] = num` and `hash_table[num + 1] = num` instead? Although this would only handle one collision then it might not be put into the hash table.

Comment: There is no `array` in python firstly.  I was simply showing you a better way than creating your own hash table which seems like a very silly thing to do given that one already exists in python.  Stuff the values however you like and use the API of the python `dict`.

Comment: @CBrown77 I don't think your question is very clear on what you want other than you're trying to create your own hash table which is a waste of effort.  Can you edit your post for more clarity?

Comment: I added an edit which might make it more clear what I'm attempting to ask

Comment: @CBrown77  If you are storing redundant values why do you need to store each copy of the redundant values?  Using `dict` you can get all of the `keys` which are your values, and if you store the count of each key in the hash table it saves space.  You can use `dict.has_key(val)` to see if your table has the value and `key_count = dict[va]` to get the number of redundancies if you do like I have shown in my code.

Comment: @CBrown77 Look at my most recent edit.  This will do something similar to what you want.  Ignore that I'm storing the count of each element and replace with whatever you like.